# How to mock LocalDatTime.now() using mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockito

I'm writing unit test to my business class and I would like to mock LocalDateTime to a specific time according to my test. Here is my function:

```
    private fun isExpired(access: Access): Boolean {
        return access.validUntil.isAfter(LocalDateTime.now())
    }
```

How can I mock `LocalDateTime.now()`?

Comment: why cant you use the "of" method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-int-java.time.Month-int-int-int-int-

Comment: Why should I pass localdatetime as function parameter? Is not possible to mock it?

Comment: now is a static method of the final class, something Mockito has trouble mocking : https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#mockito-2x-specific-limitations

Comment: By the way, I cannot imagine a case where calling `LocalDateTime.now` is the right thing to do. That type cannot represent a moment, is not a point on the timeline, because it purposely lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So using that class to capture the current moment makes no sense. I would bet you really need `Instant.now` or `ZonedDateTime.now` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is that you inject a dependency on a `Clock` and use that in your method. Apologies that I've converted to Java as I'm not too familiar with kotlin.

```
class ClassToTest {
    private final Clock;

    public ClassToTest(Clock clock) {
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    private boolean isExpired(Access access) {
        return access.validUntil.isAfter(LocalDateTime.now(clock));
    }
}
```

And the test that uses a fixed 'now' would look like:

```
@Test
void testIsExpired() {
    Clock clock = mock(Clock.class);
    when(clock.instant()).thenReturn(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1000L));
    when(clock.getZone()).thenReturn(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    ClassToTest test = new ClassToTest(clock);
    assertThat(test.isExpired(access))...
}
```

You specifically asked about mocking but you could achieve the same with a constant clock:

```
@Test
void testIsExpired() {
    Clock clock = Clock.fixed(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1000L), ZoneOffset.UTC);
    ClassToTest test = new ClassToTest(clock);
    assertThat(test.isExpired(access))...
}
```

Your production code would inject whichever clock you want (such as a particular TZ, local TZ, clocks that tick each second etc.) which are all created using static `Clock` methods. The ability to change clocks is often a useful feature to have on top of its value for testing.

Comment: Should I follow the same idea for `HttpClient` and `HttpRequest`?

Comment: This scenario is _precisely_ why the `Clock` is part of the API. I'll note that it's not entirely unreasonable to have `private Clock clock = systemUTC()` and a setter that is normally unused.